# Expected: list seperator or ) when using Range

Tags: vba, excel-2010

Trying to calculate the average of a large number of cells on an excel sheet. Try to give it the range of cells to use but get Expected: list separator or )
lu is D2545 and rl is L2669. Code should return the average value of cells D2545:L2669

```
lu = "D" & EUD_P_Start + 1

rl = Split((Columns(Sheets("Input").Range("C13") + 3).Address(, 0)), ":")(0) & EUD_P_End + 1

Pavg = Application.Average(Range(lu:rl))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `lu` and `rl` are valid addresses:

```
Pavg = Application.Average(Range(lu & ":" & rl))
```

Comment: That was it, knew it had to be something simple. Thank you.